# Resize map on window resize

Tags: html, css

I'm buidling a dashboard, and I need my map to change size when the window changes size.

I use the @media rule to adapt the dashboard to mobile devices, but I the window is resized my map overlaps the right sidebar.

I'm trying to fix it at the bottom of the screen and resize it in a responsive way when the window is resized.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([45.505, -73.19], 9); // Set initial coordinates and zoom level
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* For mobile phones: */

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.map {
  width: 100%;
  flex-basis: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  html,
  body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans';
  }
  .row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
  }
  [class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {
    width: 10%;
    align-items: normal;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
    align-items: normal;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 25%;
    align-items: normal;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-8 {
    width: 65%;
    display: block;
  }
  .col-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-12 {
    width: 100%;
    align-items: normal;
  }
  .column {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: center;
  }
  .left-sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  }
  .right-sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 160px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .map {
    flex: 1;
    height: calc(100vh - 260px);
    margin-bottom: -15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png" type="image/png" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-locatecontrol/v0.43.0/L.Control.Locate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.1/list.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-locatecontrol/v0.43.0/L.Control.Locate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>

</style>

<body>
  <div class="col-12">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="left-sidebar col-1">
      <div>
        <h5>Filter by :</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="div-selectors">
        <h5>Name</h5>
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <select onclick="handleData(this.id, this.value)" name="name" class="selectors" type="hidden" style="width:150px">
            <option></option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="div-selectors">
        <h5>Role</h5>
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <select onclick="handleData(this.id, this.value)" name="job" class="selectors" type="hidden" style="width:150px">
            <option></option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8 main-container">
    <div class="container-fluid main-data">
      <div class="col-3 column">
        <h3></h3>
        <h5 class="main-data">Number of employees</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 column">
        <h3></h3>
        <h5 class="main-data">Number of local jobs</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 column">
        <h3></h3>
        <h5 class="main-data">Number of non-local jobs</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 column">
        <h3></h3>
        <h5 class="main-data">% of local jobs</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="map" id="map"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="right-sidebar col-3">
      <div id="data-header">
        <h5>Additionnal infos</h5>
        <h2 id="geo-viz"></h2>
        <p id="date-data"></p>
      </div>
      <div></div>
      <h5>Top jobs</h5>
      <div class="table-container">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="column" class="table-header">Job</th>
              <th scope="column" class="table-header">Type</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="data-table">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: 1. Make sure you reset all styles to `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` in this case when you set `width: 100%` that already has margins or padding, it will not expand outside the screen. 2. If parent element is set to `display flex` or `width: 100%` / `height: 100%` then setting `flex-grow: 1` for a child will make child occupy all area inside parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Added (4 times) 'style="width: 100%"' in div-selector.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([45.505, -73.19], 9); // Set initial coordinates and zoom level
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* For mobile phones: */

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.map {
  width: 100%;
  flex-basis: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  html,
  body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans';
  }
  .row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
  }
  [class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {
    width: 10%;
    align-items: normal;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
    align-items: normal;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 25%;
    align-items: normal;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-8 {
    width: 65%;
    display: block;
  }
  .col-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-12 {
    width: 100%;
    align-items: normal;
  }
  .column {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: center;
  }
  .left-sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  }
  .right-sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 160px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .map {
    flex: 1;
    height: calc(100vh - 260px);
    margin-bottom: -15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png" type="image/png" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-locatecontrol/v0.43.0/L.Control.Locate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.1/list.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-locatecontrol/v0.43.0/L.Control.Locate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>

</style>

<body>
  <div class="col-12">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="left-sidebar col-1">
      <div>
        <h5>Filter by :</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="div-selectors" style="width: 100%">
        <h5>Name</h5>
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <select onclick="handleData(this.id, this.value)" name="name" class="selectors" type="hidden" style="width: 100%">
            <option></option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="div-selectors" style="width: 100%">
        <h5>Role</h5>
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <select onclick="handleData(this.id, this.value)" name="job" class="selectors" type="hidden" style="width: 100%">
            <option></option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8 main-container">
    <div class="container-fluid main-data">
      <div class="col-3 column">
        <h3></h3>
        <h5 class="main-data">Number of employees</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 column">
        <h3></h3>
        <h5 class="main-data">Number of local jobs</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 column">
        <h3></h3>
        <h5 class="main-data">Number of non-local jobs</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 column">
        <h3></h3>
        <h5 class="main-data">% of local jobs</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="map" id="map"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="right-sidebar col-3">
      <div id="data-header">
        <h5>Additionnal infos</h5>
        <h2 id="geo-viz"></h2>
        <p id="date-data"></p>
      </div>
      <div></div>
      <h5>Top jobs</h5>
      <div class="table-container">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="column" class="table-header">Job</th>
              <th scope="column" class="table-header">Type</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="data-table">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).